# Why doesn't this JavaScript code work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't this work in IE10? It works fine with Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <label for="NoOfRooms">Select number of rooms required</label>
    <select id="NoOfRooms" onchange="showHide()">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">1 room</option>
        <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
        <option value="3">3 rooms</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label id="Room1TypeLabel" for="Room1Type" class="inline">Room 1:</label>
    <select id="Room1Type">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Single</option>
        <option value="2">Double</option>
        <option value="3">Triple</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label id="Room2TypeLabel" for="Room2Type" class="hidden">Room 2:</label>
    <select id="Room2Type" class="hidden">
        <option value="1">Single</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Double</option>
        <option value="3">Triple</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label id="Room3TypeLabel" for="Room1Type" class="hidden">Room 3:</label>
    <select id="Room3Type" class="hidden">
        <option value="1">Single</option>
        <option value="2">Double</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">Triple</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showHide() {
    "use strict";
    var NoOfRooms = document.getElementById("NoOfRooms");
    var NoOfRoomsValue = NoOfRooms.options[NoOfRooms.selectedIndex].value;
    if (NoOfRoomsValue == 2) {
        Room2Type.style.display = "inline";
        Room3Type.style.display = "none";
        Room2TypeLabel.style.display = "inline";
        Room3TypeLabel.style.display = "none";
    } else if (NoOfRoomsValue == 3) {
        Room2Type.style.display = "inline";
        Room3Type.style.display = "inline";
        Room2TypeLabel.style.display = "inline";
        Room3TypeLabel.style.display = "inline";
    } else if (NoOfRoomsValue == 1) {
        Room2Type.style.display = "none";
        Room3Type.style.display = "none";
        Room2TypeLabel.style.display = "none";
        Room3TypeLabel.style.display = "none";
    } else alert("Error. Please try again.");
}
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
            display: none;
        }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQVMF/1/).

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work in Chrome, either.

Comment: What's it supposed to do?

Comment: you cannot hide `option` elements. You can only add/remove them.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: sorry guys code updated on Fiddle. It suppose to show/hide form elements depending on the selection of rooms.
@Tim it works in Chrome..

Comment: Firefox on mac doesn't do anything either, at least the fiddle isn't working.

Comment: fiddle isn't working correcltly..

Comment: IE is a developers nightmare. So bad for IE8 compatibility I finally started telling people to install chrome frame which is IE with a chrome engine. Sorry mate new IE will have bugs. That you can bank on.  I ran your script in chrome worked just fine for me. The other guys are just running into the oldest jsfiddle bug in the book don't pay attention to them. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you included the full script but it wasn't working on Firefox, for me anyway.

I'd recommend wrapping the fields in divs so you don't need to toggle each label/input. You can keep the onchange= attributes out of the html by assigning the event directly, using a library is helpful at cross-browser compat.

I threw it in some jquery (which might be overkill if you're only doing this single bit of js, but I doubt you are) and it works well:

It needs some cleanup but I threw it together:

```
$(function(){

    $('#NoOfRooms').change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 1){
            $('#room1').show();
            $('#room2, #room3').hide();
        }
        else if( $(this).val() == 2){
            $('#room1,#room2').show();
            $('#room3').hide();
        }
        else if( $(this).val() == 3){
            $('div').show();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uQVMF/4/

Using a loop or a more dynamic way of showing the right fields is best, especially if you use more than three room fields.

Comment: works fine. Thank you. any idea the code i wrote does not work under ie?

Comment: The code you wrote wasn't working for me in firefox, the onchange event wasn't even firing but that may just be a fiddle issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so a couple of issues at work here:

First the fiddle wasn't working because JSFiddle automatically wraps your code in the jquery onLoad function.  Switching "onLoad" to "No Wrap" on the left sidebar of JSFiddle fixes this problem and gets the code working in Chrome and Firefox.

Second IE requires that onchange be onChange.

Last you need to define the Room2Type, Room3Type, Room2TypeLabel, etc variables the same way you did with the select:

```
document.getElementById("Room2Type").style
```

But all of the above is really just so you understand why your code wasn't working.  You really should be using something along the lines of what @BotskoNet wrote going forward.